# Why do some of my questions have a (-2) to reputation?

Tags: support, reputation

How do I get -2 Reputation for some of my questions?  They are sincere questions.  And I don't have the reputation to tag this with reputation.

Comment: Do I only get to ask so many questions in a day? Because this one got -2 as well :(

Comment: No, that's not the issue. This is getting moved to our meta site shortly, where it's the appropriate place to ask questions like this.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

So, the short answer is: because someone thought they were unclear, not researched, or not useful, and downvoted them.

The long answer is: You probably need to do some exploring of the [help centre](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help). In particular, [our page on reputation](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) explains all the details of how reputation works.

Stack Exchange is a community that works differently to regular forums, and has its own rules and guidelines. There are a lot of potential pitfalls for a new user, so I really can't recommend strongly enough that you skim through the help centre to learn how things work around here. A quick glance through some of the meta questions in the [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) category might be helpful too.

Answer (score 4):

Questions get upvoted & downvoted by readers, based on whether they think the question is a good one or not.

Hovering over the up/down buttons gives you a quick summary of the criteria:

> This question shows research effort; it is useful and clear

For more information on how the site works, you can read the [tour](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help) pages.